# Erro no método de atualização de dados junto ao banco

Tags: java, mysql

Estou utilizando o `MySQL`  e Java no netbeans, porém  o código da string  SQL não atualiza. Não sei o que pode estar dando erro, pois já verifiquei o sql e aparentemente está ok.

Tenho na minha classe `DAO`, o método `update` e o `pesquisaCriterio`, e chamo no meu form. Quando tento atualizar, ele dá erro no `pesquisarCriterio` e no `update. Segue o código da DAO e de como estou chamando no form:

Tenho duas fk que estão cadastradas no meu banco, desde já agradeço quem puder me ajudar.
Abaixo segue a linha do código atualizar e pesquisar critério na classe DAO.

**ReservaDAO**

```
 public boolean atualizar(Object obj) {
        Reserva reservaVO;

        if (obj instanceof Reserva) {
            reservaVO = (Reserva) obj; //converte de Object para Reserva
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        String sql = "UPDATE reserva SET tipoReserva = '" + reservaVO.getTipoReserva()
                + "', dataReserva = '" + reservaVO.getDataReserva()
                + "', dataEntrada = '" + reservaVO.getDataEntrada()
                + "', dataSaida = '" + reservaVO.getDataSaida()
                + "', horarioEntrada = '" + reservaVO.getHorarioEntrada()
                + "', horarioSaida = '" + reservaVO.getHorarioSaida()
                + "', qtdPessoas = '" + reservaVO.getQtdPessoas()
                + "', status = '" + reservaVO.getStatus()
                + "', codHospede = '" + reservaVO.getCodHospede()
                + "', codApartamento = '" + reservaVO.getCodApartamento()
                + "' WHERE codReserva = '" + reservaVO.getCodReserva() + "'";
        try {

            getBanco().abrir();
            Statement stm = getBanco().getConexao().createStatement();
            if (stm.executeUpdate(sql) > 0) {
                getBanco().fechar();
                return true;
            } else {
                getBanco().fechar();
                return false;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            getBanco().fechar();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**ReservaDAO - pesquisarCriterio**

```
public Object pesquisarCriterio(String criterio) {

        Reserva reservaVO = null;
        String sql = "SELECT r.codReserva , H.nome, A.numeroApto,"
                + " r.tipoReserva , r.dataReserva , r.dataEntrada ,"
                + " r.dataSaida , r.horarioEntrada , r.horarioSaida ,"
                + " qtdPessoas , r.status  "
                + " FROM reserva r"
                + " INNER JOIN Hospede AS H ON  r.codReserva = H.codHospede "
                + " INNER JOIN Apartamento AS A ON ( r.codReserva = A.codApartamento) "
                + " WHERE r.codReserva " + criterio + " Order by codReserva" ;
        getBanco().abrir();
        try {
            Statement stm = getBanco().getConexao().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
            if (rs.next() == true) { //Achou
                reservaVO = new Reserva();
                reservaVO.setCodReserva(rs.getInt("codReserva"));
                reservaVO.setCodHospede(rs.getInt("codHospede"));
                reservaVO.setCodApartamento(rs.getInt("codApartamento"));
                reservaVO.setTipoReserva(rs.getString("tipoReserva"));
                reservaVO.setDataReserva(rs.getDate("dataReserva"));
                reservaVO.setDataEntrada(rs.getDate("dataEntrada"));
                reservaVO.setDataSaida(rs.getDate("dataSaida"));
                reservaVO.setHorarioEntrada(rs.getString("horarioEntrada"));
                reservaVO.setHorarioSaida(rs.getString("horarioSaida"));
                reservaVO.setQtdPessoas(rs.getString("qtdPessoas"));
                reservaVO.setStatus(rs.getString("status"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return reservaVO;
    }
```

**Tela**

```
Reserva reserva1 = new Reserva();
        Calendar cal;
        int d, m, a;//Variaveis para usar com calendario
        reserva1 = (Reserva) reservaDAO.pesquisarCriterio(txtNomeHospede.getText());
        if (reserva1.getCodReserva() != 0) {
        } else {
            if (!txtNomeHospede.getText().isEmpty()&& !txtNumero.getText().isEmpty()
                  && !txtQtdPessoas.getText().isEmpty()) {
                reserva1.setCodHospede(Integer.parseInt(txtNomeHospede.getText()));
                reserva1.setCodApartamento(Integer.parseInt(txtNumero.getText()));
                reserva1.setTipoReserva(String.valueOf(cmbTipoReserva.getSelectedItem
                cal = dcDataReserva.getCalendar();
                d = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                m = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                a = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900;
                reserva1.setDataReserva(new Date(a, m, d));
                cal = dcDataEntrada.getCalendar();
                d = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                m = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                a = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900;
                reserva1.setDataEntrada(new Date(a, m, d));
                cal = dcDataSaida.getCalendar();
                d = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                m = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                a = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900;
                reserva1.setDataSaida(new Date(a, m, d));

                reserva1.setHorarioEntrada(txtHorarioEntrada.getText());
                reserva1.setHorarioSaida(txtHorarioSaida.getText());
                reserva1.setQtdPessoas(txtQtdPessoas.getText());
                reserva1.setStatus(String.valueOf(cmbStatus.getSelectedItem()));      
                reservaDAO.atualizar(reserva1);
                limparCampos();
                dcDataReserva.setCalendar(null);
                dcDataEntrada.setCalendar(null);
                dcDataSaida.setCalendar(null);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Dados da Reserva atualizado com sucesso!");
                conReserva.executaSQL("select *from reserva");
                try {
                    modeloTabelaReserva.setResult(conReserva.resultset);
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JFCadProduto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

Erro:

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Adriana Ferreira Order by codReserva' at line 1
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2788)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2738)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1617)
 at DAO.ReservaDAO.pesquisarCriterio(ReservaDAO.java:196)
 at GUI.JFCadReserva.btnAtualizarActionPerformed(JFCadReserva.java:740)
 at GUI.JFCadReserva.access$1000(JFCadReserva.java:26)
 at GUI.JFCadReserva$11.actionPerformed(JFCadReserva.java:459)
```

Comment: Bem vinda ao sopt. Adicione na pergunta o erro que dá no método update.

Comment: Erro: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Adriana Ferreira Order by codReserva' at line 1
 at DAO.ReservaDAO.pesquisarCriterio(ReservaDAO.java:196)
 at GUI.JFCadReserva.btnAtualizarActionPerformed(JFCadReserva.java:740)

Comment: Lizy, copie o erro completo, clique em [edit] e adicione no final da pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nessa linha:

```
String sql = "SELECT r.codReserva , H.nome, A.numeroApto,"
                + " r.tipoReserva , r.dataReserva , r.dataEntrada ,"
                + " r.dataSaida , r.horarioEntrada , r.horarioSaida ,"
                + " qtdPessoas , r.status  "
                + " FROM reserva r"
                + " INNER JOIN Hospede AS H ON  r.codReserva = H.codHospede "
                + " INNER JOIN Apartamento AS A ON ( r.codReserva = A.codApartamento) "
                + " WHERE r.codReserva " + criterio + " Order by codReserva" ;
```

há um erro de sintaxe em `WHERE r.codReserva " + criterio + " Order by codReserva"`, você esqueceu de adicionar a condição que quer fazer na cláusula `where`. Imagino que o esperado seja:

```
String sql = "SELECT r.codReserva , H.nome, A.numeroApto,"
                + " r.tipoReserva , r.dataReserva , r.dataEntrada ,"
                + " r.dataSaida , r.horarioEntrada , r.horarioSaida ,"
                + " qtdPessoas , r.status  "
                + " FROM reserva r"
                + " INNER JOIN Hospede AS H ON  r.codReserva = H.codHospede "
                + " INNER JOIN Apartamento AS A ON ( r.codReserva = A.codApartamento) "
                + " WHERE r.codReserva = " + criterio + " Order by codReserva" ;
```

Comment: Diego f. - sim mas vc saberia como resolver??

Comment: @Lizy Na resposta já tem a solução.

Comment: @Lizy conseguiu resolver?

Comment: @Lizy sugiro que avalie trocar a forma como faz a query usando PreparedStatement, assim você separa os parametros da query, tem mais segurança contra sql injection e seu código fica mais facil de ser entendido.

Comment: Segue alguns links caso se interesse: https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/bancos-de-dados-e-jdbc/#2-9-inserindo-dados-no-banco e https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: estou utilizando o java, na minha DAO estou usando o preparedStatement só postei o sql para ver se encontrava solução na query.

Comment: @Lizy preparedStatement é uma interface do java que separa os parâmetros da query. Você está adicionando os valores diretamente na query, isso dificulta a leitura da mesma e pode ocorrer erros de sintaxe, como é o seu caso, da uma olhada nos links que mandei, fica muito mais facil pra achar erros depois.